# Replace image src attribute from HTML content

Tags: php

I made a chrome extension that reads a page content and post it to my webserver. The problem is that I need to change the src attribute from the html source to my websites´s address.

Lets go to my code (this is just a example):

```
$html = '<p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Tahoma; text-align: center;"><img style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Tahoma;" src="http://sga.ufmg.br/images/uploads/13212/MSI_civil_01.png" alt="" width="338" height="367"></p>';

$img = 'http://sga.ufmg.br/images/uploads/13212/MSI_civil_01.png';

$result = str_replace($img, 'http://asrespostazzz.com.br/questoes_img/' . $new_img_name, $html);
```

It simply wont work.... :(

I tried to use `preg_replace`, but gave me a error:

> Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: the error doesn't support what you posted for code or how you used it. Go over the manual(s) again.

Comment: it works for me, is src always the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

If you have single image element in your html this `preg_replace` will work:

```
preg_replace('/<img\ [^>]+src="([^"]+)"/', 'http://asrespostazzz.com.br/questoes_img/' . $new_img_name, $html);
```

But if you have multiple image elements then you have to build an array with replacements ( I don't know if it is approachable for your case ... some more info will be helpful). So your `preg_replace` code will look like:

```
$replacements = [
      'http://asrespostazzz.com.br/questoes_img/' . $new_img_name,
      .....
];
preg_replace('/<img\ [^>]+src="([^"]+)"/', $replacements, $html);
```